# functionName`${param1} and ${param2}` - почему и по какому принципу это работает?

Tags: javascript

```js
function getPersonInfo(one, two, three) {
  console.log(one);
  console.log(two);
  console.log(three);
}

const person = "Lydia";
const age = 21;

getPersonInfo`${person} is ${age} years old`;
```

Впервые вижу подобный вызов функции. Почему это работает? Почему это не синтаксическая ошибка? По какому принципу берется ответ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B

Comment: @Yaant черт, в первый раз об этом слышу. Век живи, век учись, что называется...

Answer (score -2):

Этот код использует шаблонные строки и тег функцию getPersonInfo. Когда мы используем шаблонные строки с тегом функции, строка и ее выражения передаются в эту функцию в качестве аргументов. В данном случае, getPersonInfo является тегом функции, а ${person} is ${age} years old - это строка шаблона.

Таким образом, при вызове getPersonInfo${person} is ${age} years old мы передаем строку шаблона и ее выражения в качестве аргументов в функцию getPersonInfo. Поэтому, этот код выведет:

["", " is ", " years old"]
Lydia
21

Здесь мы видим, что строка шаблона была разделена на массив из трех элементов: первый элемент - это пустая строка перед первым выражением, второй элемент - это строка " is ", а третий элемент - это строка " years old". Затем мы выводим каждый из аргументов функции getPersonInfo: первый аргумент - это массив из трех элементов, а второй и третий аргументы - это значения переменных person и age`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)